# How do I set kile as the default application for .tex files?

Tags: kile

Using Ubuntu 12.04. I would like to choose kile as the default application for tex files, but I run into problems. I go through

"right click" -> properties -> open with -> show other applications

but kile is not in the list, so how can I choose kile?

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer given by Yusuf is correct but in my case it was incomplete. Since I had no `Kile.desktop` file in my `/usr/share/applications` (the `.desktop` association is hidden, as Cumulus007 points out), I had to create it and simply writing `Exec=kile %F` isn't enough. This is what I put inside the `Kile.desktop` file I created using Yusuf's instructions:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Kile
Comment=LaTeX front end
Exec=kile %f
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/kile.xpm
Type=Application
Categories=Office;Database
MimeType=text/x-bibtex
```

This finally allowed me to select `Kile` as the default application to open `.tex` files.

Answer (score 7):

Open the application desktop file in /usr/share/applications and check if the "Exec" line end with this value: "%F". If that is not the case, then you'll have to append this value to this line. Here is the command used to edit the desktop file:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/<filename>.desktop
```

change the exec line from

```
Exec=kile
```

to

```
Exec=kile %F
```

and then Kile appears in the list.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now.For some reason there where no kile.desktop file.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but when I go to the folder `/usr/share/applications` there are no `.desktop` files, just application files with no extensions. The file for `Kile` isn't there, how can I create it?

Comment: Ubuntu reads .desktop files according to the FreeDesktop specification, thus displaying them as application launchers.

Follow Yusuf Felly's instructions on how to create the desktop file.

Comment: I thought that just adding `Exec=kile %F` should make it work, but that's not enough. I've added an answer explaining why it wasn't working in my case. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Open the application desktop file (in this case, `kile.desktop`) in "/usr/share/applications" and check if the `Exec` line ends with this: `%F`. If that is not the case, then you'll have to append this value to this line (with a prepending space, if needed). Here is the command used to edit the desktop file:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/kile.desktop
```

or

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/kde4/kile.desktop
```

Here kde4 might be something else.

change the exec line from:

```
Exec=kile
```

to:

```
Exec=kile %F
```

and then Kile should appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Kile isn't default in "Ubuntu". You need to install it (and its Qt/KDE dependencies) yourself using a Software manager or `sudo apt-get install kile`. If you wish, you can first run `apt-get install -s --no-install-recommends kile` to see, as a simulation, what else will come with Kile even without the recommends.

After you've installed Kile, it's possible you *still* won't see it as an option in the context menu as you have experienced. That may be a consequence of missing a `.desktop` file as described in detail here: [How do I set kile as the default application for .tex files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/147737/25656).

Answer (score 0):

My situation was a little different, but I believe the answer could be helpful here.

I am using ubuntu 16.04; the default application for opening .tex files was RStudio (i.e. when double-clicking on a tex file, it was opened in RStudio). The `kile.desktop` file already had the `Exec=kile %F` ending. To open a foo.tex file with kile (or texmaker) I had to right-click, and choose open with.

The permanent solution to change the deafult program for me was:

- open Files
- right click on the .tex file
- go to `Properties`
- go to `Open With`
- click on Texmaker (or Kile) and click `set as default`

I don't know how to do this in the command line.